# Fastest method of getting image data from a canvas as text

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, todataurl

**Background**

I am making a game that requires lots (thousands) of different images to be created so each of them can be drawn to a canvas. I can let the creation process be slow because I can do it over time, but I need to store them afterwards so I don't have to make them again. I will be storing them in a single file along with other data which is why I need them as text.

**What I mean by "image data" in the title**

Any data that can be:

- Taken from an HTML canvas element
- Stored as text
- Can be processed to form the original image and draw it to a canvas

For example, a data URI, or an array of pixels (converted to string format using JSON) could both be used to store an image as text. Both of these can also be processed to create a the original image. It is preferable that the time to process the data in order to draw it is less than the time to create it, because that would make storing it in the first place irrelevant.

But what is the quickest way to do this? My canvas width and height are 1800 and 1000. I am currently using `context.toDataURL()` and it is averaging 100ms which is too slow.

**Final Question**

What is the fastest way to get data from a canvas that can be processed to re-create it?

Comment: https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Canvas-Data-Users/Canvas-Data-2-Early-Access/ba-p/408235

Comment: ... Honestly this sounds like a bad design to me. First, your file will be huge, low end devices may just kill your page when you'll try to load it. Then, all text to bitmap will take some time, e.g a data:// URL representing a png image will have to be loaded in an Image first then decoded to be finally painted on the context. Even storing the actual pixels data will require that this data is moved to an ImageData object and then painted on the context, which is also a slow operation. If it was for reuse in the same page I would have said "create ImageBitmaps" , but these can't be stringified

Comment: In your position I would rather search for a way to make the actual generation fast enough it isn't a problem doing it every time and only if it's impossible to make it fast enough, I'd try to store the images as binary in a server, depending on what these images are, maybe even a video might be better to store these.

Comment: Parsing an array containing every pixel in JS will be slow... Have you tried saving each image in your JSON file as separate strings containing base64 encoded data?

Comment: ? Not sure to follow. If we say you go the pixel data way because it might be the actual fastest (though I didn't check), a single 1800x1000px  image converted to a JSON Array will be around 14,400,001bytes for a fully transparent image and 28,800,001bytes for a full white image. You said you have thousands of these images -> 21MB median * 1000 -> 21GB.

Comment: But then it is slow because the browser has to decode the compressed image. Back to square 1... One thing is not clear to me, why do you need to generate these even once on the front-end? Can't you make it before-hand and just serve these images normally? If they are not 1800x1000px, then you could even bundle some of them in sprite-sheets.

Comment: The first thing we should do is clear up our comments. The game I am making is a recreation of the 2D sandbox game, Terraria, so I can't pre-generate images. They have to be generated based off of a block map, and there is a data URI for each chunk. The data URI I can convert to an HTML image object pretty quickly.

Comment: The first thing you should do is clarify your question. I never played the original game, so I'm sorry if it's obvious to you, but if you can't pre-generate these images, why do you need to store them? Also, how come it's this long to generate these images? The answer to your question highly depends on the use-case, there is no single answer here that would fit every situations. So you need to make your situation as clear as possible for us to be able to help you.

Comment: I was just saying, because our comments probably won't be of use to anyone else. The reason I need to store them is because the creation process is slow so I only want to do it once. The reason it takes so long to load is probably because I programmed it badly and can't do it any better.

Comment: Well I hope our comments will help future readers to not have to ask themselves all these questions I had to ask you. Hopefully you will be able to edit the question in a way they don't even have to ask these questions, at that time I'll happily clean this thread. For now I think it is still useful. Regarding the slowness of your rendering, why don't you tell us more about what's being done? Maybe we can help there directly, there is always someone who'll know tricks that make good code works better.